# Exception string index out of bounds

Tags: java, string

i have this error in my java program, any help !!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 19
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Password_Constrainer.main(Password_Constrainer.java:31)
```

---

here is the code

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter Your Password: ");
    String inputString = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(inputString);

    if (inputString.length() < 10) // less than 10 characters
    {
        System.out.println("Validation failed, word was too short");
    } else // Contain a letter in upper case
    {
        int sum1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= inputString.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(inputString.charAt(i)))
                sum1++;
        }
        if (sum1 == 0)
            System.out.println("Validation failed, word has no Capital Letters");
```

can you help me in this ??

Comment: Your string is 19 or less characters in length.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if we don't have idea what the string is? Please post the related code.

Comment: check the size of your Sring before doing some action yourString.length().

Comment: oooooooooooh finally, thank you guys >>> i love u all :D  <3

Comment: Thank @Marco Acierno by clicking the checkmark next to his answer, if thats the answer you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'i' value can't be equal to inputString's length . So , change

```
i <= inputString.length()
```

to

```
i < inputString.length()
```

in loop.

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= inputString.length(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
```

If you do `<=` It will iterate in `inputString.length()` index, char which not exists.